# ASP.NET Excel and PDF Download Appending a "[1]" to my .PDF/.XLS Extension

Tags: asp.net, mime-types

I have a web form page that is supposed to be able to write content of a Crystal Report out to either a pdf or excel document depending on which selection a user makes.

I've got 2 problems:

1. For both .pdf and .xls extensions, there is a bracket with a one
   inside it being appended to the extension IE: fileName.xls'[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzRbz.gif)'
2. If a user selects an excel document, in IE the file download prompt
   appears and asks if we want to save or open the file:

[image]

The PDF File saves just fine, however if we choose to open the excel file, it opens an Explorer window and we get garbage...

Here's our code:

```
try
{
    permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, output);
    fs = File.Open(output, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    fileName = fileName + '.' + extn;
    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachments;filename=\"" + fileName + ".\"" + extn);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachments;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());

    switch ("." + extn)
    {
        case ".pdf":
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            break;
        case ".xls":
            //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader(".xls", "application/excel");
            //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
            //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");

            break;
        case ".txt":
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/notepad");
            break;

    }
    FileInfo info = new FileInfo(output);
    info.Delete();
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    if (fs != null)
        fs.Close();
}
```

I've been researching the phenomena of people experiencing "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzRbz.gif)" being appended to an extension, however haven't found much out there on it and have debugged the code and confirmed that the extension is clean.

My next guess is something's going on in the Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray); line or the mime types or content headers...

thanks in advance for any assistance

doug

Comment: Where do you set `extn`?

Comment: extn = (string)grdReports.DataKeys[rowIndex]["REPORTOUTPUTTYPE"];

Answer (score 0):

I had done a similar thing in my project.
I have pasted the code I ued below.
I think, you jut replace the line. 
    Response.AppendHeader(".xls", "application/excel");
with
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
        string type = "";
        // set known types based on file extension 
        if (ext != null)
        {
            switch (ext.ToLower())
            {
                case ".htm":
                case ".html":
                    type = "text/HTML";
                    break;


                case ".txt":
                    type = "text/plain";
                    break;


                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                case ".rtf":
                    type = "Application/msword";
                    break;

                case ".pdf":
                    type = "application/pdf";
                    break;

                case ".csv":
                case ".xlsx":
                    type = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    break;
            }
        }
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + name);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Response.ContentType = type;
        }
        Response.WriteFile(path);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Tried both of these, however got the same result.

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

Answer (score 0):

Extend your `switch` to the following:

```
switch ("." + extn)
{
    // case ".pdf":
    // ...

    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

If the exception is thrown, this might give you a hint on what's going wrong.